# Why aren't flags in chat anonymous?

Tags: support, chat

How is this user finding out information about flagging?

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8039304#8039304

what is breaking the anonymity of the flag system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He's guessing. Spam/Offensive flags in chat are anonymous, even to moderators. There are also moderator flags, which are not anonymous to moderators, but 10k users can't see those.

The anonymity of flags is not an invitation to misuse them (I'm talking about the general case, not any specific incident). If there is enough abuse of chat flags, we moderators will ask SE to help us deal with it, as they can still find out who is flagging, even for the spam/offensive flags.

Comment: so why can he see flags? like [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8043474#8043474)

Comment: 10k+ users can see spam/offensive flags (and act on them), but they cannot see *who* cast the flag.